# A ******* Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, poetry

Here’s a quickie. Won’t take that long to solve. The title holds a clue. Make sure to explain it in your answer. Good luck!

> The first that starts but the last that ends,
>   Plus a synonym for making amends,
>   Of just above, keep only the first three plus two,
>   Then that mixed up is a word for you.

Hint:

> The exact number of asterisks in the title doesn't matter. What they're doing does.

Comment: Is this a hint for “A Research Paper”?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton nope- that puzzle is entirely solvable on its own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To resurrect this 11-month-old 'quickie' (!), perhaps this is:

> A **censor's** riddle

*The first that starts but the last that ends,*

> The first letter of 'starts' is '**S**'; the last letter of 'ends' is also '**S**'.

*Plus a synonym for making amends,*

> A synonym for 'making amends' is '*reconciling*'.

*Of just above, keep only the first three plus two,*

> The first five ('three plus two') letters of 'reconciling' (the word clued 'just above' this line) are '**RECON**'.

*Then that mixed up is a word for you.*

> A suitable anagram of *SSRECON* (a combination of all letters from earlier clues) could therefore be **CENSORS** or **CENSOR'S**. This fits with the asterisk-laden title since the use of asterisks in this way is a common printer's technique for demonstrating that sensitive information or profanity has been redacted or '*censored*'.

Comment: Brilliant to see these veteran questions being resolved, a fifth necromancer badge well deserved! (Plus the other ones which haven't got to 5 points yet.)

Answer (score 2):

Is it..

> REMAKER ?

First that starts but last that ends

> don't start with this hint, but end with it

synonym for making amends

> make reparations

of just above, keep only first three plus two

> MAKe REparations --> makre

Then that mixed up is a word for you

> makre --> maker

First that starts but last that ends

> RE-mak-ER

title

> seven asterisks, seven letters in 'remaker'

Answer (score 2):

The word is:

> Eraser

The first that starts but the last that ends,

> Er is at the beginning and end of the word

Plus a synonym for making amends,

> Used to fix (amend) errors/mistakes

Of just above, keep only the first three plus two,

> **Erase**r

Then that mixed up is a word for you.

> How about: A Seer

Title:

> First I thought censorship, but I guess it's removing the word in the title, thus erasing it.

Comment: (rot13) qbag nyjnlf vtaber svefg vzcerffvbaf

Answer (score 0):

Just trying something:

> The first that starts but the last that ends    ---  you start and end with an apolgy? --- or a logging would be more usefull for the answer

next:

> Plus a synonym for "making amends", --- apology

so from here on i looked at your hint:

> of just above, keep only the first (three plus two) --- apolo
>  Then that mixed up is a word for you. --- apologs --- which would fit the 7*

used wiki:

> An apologue or apolog (from the Greek ἀπόλογος, a "statement" or "account") is a brief fable or allegorical story with pointed or exaggerated details,

Answer (score 0):

Just trying something:

The first that starts but the last that ends:

> The letter 's' is the first one in the word "starts" but the last one in the word "ends".

Plus a synonym for making amends,

> Not quite a synonym, but you definitely should make amends to someone you have been *[gutting](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gutting)*.

Of just above, keep only the first three plus two,

> If I keep only the first three plus two letters of "just above", I get j,u,s,a,b.

Then that mixed up is a word for you.

> what we have is s, g, u, t, t, i, n, g, j, u, s, a, b

That's enough to make

> a **subjugating** riddle

Even if

> Extra 's' and 't' remain